# how can i print two character of a string if it's even or one if it's odd?

Tags: python

how can one find middle character in a string if the string is odd, or the two middle if the string is even? I have been trying but coming up empty-handed. i will appreciate any help.

```
def middle(s):
    for length in userInput:
        if  len(userInput) % 2 == 0:
            return i
        elif len(userInput) % 2 != 0:
```

this is what i have so far. i know it needs to be different, i'm just not sure how to change it.
thanks

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far

Comment: def middle(s):
    for length in userInput:
        if  len(userInput) % 2 == 0:
            return i
        elif len(userInput) % 2 != 0:

Comment: and i know that's not even close.. i'm just stuck.

Comment: Okay, reason through it: you don't need a loop. Implement exactly what you said in your question: if the length of the string is cleanly divisible by two, print the middle two characters; else, print the middle one. Edit your code in your question; comments are not good for code, and really really bad for Python code. Then see which part of what I said give you trouble. Hint: 2 characters at position `x` can be obtained with `str[x:x+2]`

Comment: Can you put your full code inside the question? It looks like you missed some of it in your copy paste (plus it's hard to read in a comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure where `userInput` is defined or why you're iterating, but this will return what you're looking for from string `s`:

```
 def middle(s):
    s_len = len(s)
    if s_len % 2 == 0:
        return s[int(s_len/2)-1:int(s_len/2)+1]
    else:
        return s[int(s_len/2)]
```

Comment: Thanks it work. After writing so many codes,simple ones like this seem so difficult XD.... anyway thanks a lot gr1zzly be4r

Comment: You're welcome. You should mark it as correct so that others will know too!